# usage question: punished his drug possession

Tags: word-usage, collocations

Is the following use of "punished" natural?

> The court punished his drug possession.

Comment: "The court punished _him for_ possessing drugs" - but other terms like _penalized, found him guilty of, sentenced him for_ would be more natural. Naughty children are punished.

Comment: This is a lot like your earlier question about "penalize." Looking more closely at Google this time, I think your guess then was correct. You will find "punish the crime," but it seems always to be in the abstract. I.e., "We punish the crime of drug possession" describes a generalization. But Kate Bunting is correct about a specific instance of a crime. We punish the criminal, not the event.

Comment: I found this, though: "He argues that the district court punished his exercise of the privilege against self-incrimination by refusing to continue the action during the pendency . . ."

Comment: And this:  "He procured entry only by making false answers to certain questions which the law then in force required him to answer . That law , however , merely punished his act by imposing a fine and subjecting him to deportation . . . "